# Overview of Android animation systems

Tags: android, animation

Android has had about 5 or 6 different animation systems over the years, as they realise that each one doesn't really make animations easy. This makes it *really* confusing to do animations, as searches often bring up years-old SO questions which use old methods.

As far as I know there are:

- Android 1: [View Animation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html)
- Android 3: [Property Animation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html)
- Android 4.4: [Scenes and Transitions](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#Animations)

I'm pretty sure I've missed some. Is there a good comprehensive overview anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

You can find almost in depth tutorials on Android Animations here https://teamtreehouse.com/library/animations-and-transitions [PAID]

For basic animations you can check out: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html
or http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_animations.htm

Material Design Animations:
https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html

Some random articles on Android Animations
 
http://frogermcs.github.io/InstaMaterial-concept-part-5-like_action_effects/
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/implementing-material-design-in-your.html

And if you don't want to code from scratch, you can just pick up a library which will do the work for you here 
https://android-arsenal.com/tag/6

This are some docs which helped me get into Android Animations, hope it helps.

Comment: Yes it is. Its divided into 4 parts covering Animations Basics, The Transitions Framework, Shared Element Transitions, Activity Transitions Advanced Topics. I hope my answer solved your doubt.